# Driving a transistor or CMOS gate using 50 μA of low voltage (~60 mV)?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, cmos, mosfet-driver

I was wondering if it's possible to have a tiny input current (60 mV, 50 μA) open a gate or transistor, allowing a 9 V battery to have a line to a high-impedance microcontroller digital input. The microcontroller only needs about 1.5 V to be triggered.

Is there a low-current transistor out there that can accomplish this?

Other input options include a 5 V output from one of the microcontroller's voltage-regulated pins, which could be used in place of the 9 V battery if there's a transistor or CMOS design with enough gain to reach 1.5 V already.

I'm trying to minimize components - I have another design that already works with about 5 extra components attached, but I'd be interested to see if just this transistor could work better than that.

Comment: Its pretty hard to understand what you are really trying to do. Where does the 20mV come from? Can you draw a schematic of what youre trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do people always ask me this on this site? I just want to get at least 1.5V out of a small input current. I have a 9V source for the circuit or alternatively a 5V source... Can't I just collect the 9V, and put the small current at the "base" of the transistor, and emit >= 1.5V? With what type of transistor on DigiKey or Mouser? I want the transistor to be trigger-happy given this small amount of current

Comment: Because it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. FETs are driven by voltage and 60mV is not enough.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138258/discussion-on-question-by-nick-carraway-driving-a-transistor-or-cmos-gate-using).

Comment: @nickcarraway If the input is AC, you can use a biasing circuit to shift the 0-60mV upwards so it's more like 2.5-2.56V (for example), smack in the middle of the voltage range that your chosen transistor amplifies the best. But if it's DC, that's more complicated. So again, can you tell us more about the input?

Comment: Well it’s in chat now - I have a working version with that many components, looking to minimize them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to perform a simulation with a [JFET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFET) [LSK170A](https://www.linearsystems.com/lsdata/datasheets/LSK170_Datasheet_Rev_A22), where a signal of 0-100 mV produces an output of 1.39V to 526mV. It is 1.07V at 60mV. That JFET has a very high [Beta](https://www.youspice.com/spice-modeling-of-a-jfet-from-datasheet/) (transconductance coefficient) of 37.86m (and costs $11 each!). A JFET is also known as a [depletion mode](https://eepower.com/technical-articles/what-are-depletion-mode-mosfets/#) device.

So here is my simulation. I arrived at the resistor values empirically (plug and play), so it might be possible to achieve higher gain. There are certainly better (and cheaper) ways to amplify a 60 mV signal, but this seems to be about the only way to do so with a single device.

[image: JFET Simulation]

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering if it's possible to have a tiny input current (**60 mV**,
> 50 μA) open a gate or transistor, allowing a 9 V battery to have a
> line to a high-impedance microcontroller digital input. The
> microcontroller only needs about 1.5 V to be triggered.
>
> Is there a low-current transistor out there that can accomplish this?

The input current won't be a problem, but the low voltage is. Silicon [bipolar junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor) transistors need about 0.6 V between Base and Emitter to turn them on. Enhancement mode [MOSFETs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) need 0.5 V or more between Gate and Source. Exotic 'Zero Threshold' FETs start turning on at close to 0 V, but only pass a few microamps at 60 mV.

You might be able to bias the transistor input with no extra components, but it would be temperature sensitive and susceptible to noise. So the direct answer to your question is no, there are no 'low current' transistors that will do the job because none have a low enough drive voltage.

Then you must consider the topology. You need a device that amplifies a signal going from (presumably) 0 V when off to 60 mV when on, to a logic level of close to 0 V when off to 1.5 V when on. This means the circuit must have a *non-inverting* gain of at least 1.5/0.06 = 25. But a single transistor can only have gain greater than 1 in an *inverting* topology (ie. Common Emitter or Common Source configuration). To get a non-inverting output you need two transistor stages or a more sophisticated device.

> I'm trying to minimize components - I have another design that already
> works with about 5 extra components attached, but I'd be interested to
> see if just this transistor could work better than that.

A single transistor won't do it, but there are other devices that could, including some that need a couple of extra components and some that might do it alone.

For example you could use a comparator IC, possibly with built in voltage reference (eg. [LTC1540](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1540fb.pdf)), with 2 resistors to set the threshold voltage.

Or you could use a tiny MCU like the Microchip [PIC10F322](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/PIC10F322), which has an 8 bit A/D converter that theoretically can measure voltages as low as 20 mV on a 5 V supply.

But having the least components might not be the best for you. The tiny MCU needs to be programmed. Is that complication worth the saving of two resistors? And finding a supplier with the 'ideal' component in stock may be difficult these days.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning noise and temperature as it will likely apply to other people searching this question. For me I actually don't need the precise logic levels. It's a strange use case where it can be trigger-happy (and make mistakes) and still be functional